# How would I use differentials to solve this problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

What rules would I be using to solve this problem, and how would I use the differentials to find the derivative?

> $\text{Find } dy/dx\colon x^{2}-4xy+y^2 = 4.$

Comment: Are you familiar with Implicit Differentiation?

Comment: Alternative hint: complete the square in $\,y\,$ for $\,(y-2x)^2=3x^2+4\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 
$$
x^2-4xy+y^2=4
$$
then applying the derivative operator $d$ we have
$$
2xdx-4xdy-4ydx+2ydy=0\implies xdx-2xdy-2ydx+ydy=0\\
\implies x-2x\frac{dy}{dx}-2y+y\frac{dy}{dx}=0\\
\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2y-x}{y-2x}
$$
Where we solved for the term $\frac{dy}{dx}$ treating the above symbols as differentials.